# Check if a string contains only English letters, numbers, underscores, dots (like Instagram username) in Kotlin

Tags: string, kotlin

I want to check if a string contains only letters, numbers, underscores, dots like Instagram. I've used Regex but the result wasn't right. Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you mean *Latin* characters? I never heard of English ones... Can you show us the regex you tried and some code around that shows how you tried it?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Bear in mind that this community isn't free code writing service, you can ask anything that doesn't work as expected with a reproducible example (in order for others to examine what you've did wrong)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in case if someone needs it. I've used this website to complete the code: https://www.regextester.com/93960

```
private val USERNAME_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("""^[_A-z0-9]*((\s)*[_A-z0-9])*${'$'}""")
if (PASSWORD_PATTERN.matcher(YOUR_STRING).matches()) {
                return true
            } else {
                return false
            }
```

Comment: That's probably not what you want: `A-z` includes not only the upper-case letters `A-Z` and the lower-case ones `a-z`, but everything between `Z` and `a`, i.e. `[` `\ ` `]` `^` `_` and `\``.  Use `A-Za-z` if you only want the basic Latin letters.

Answer (score 1):

This should work
^(?!.*..)(?!.*.$)[^\W][\w.]{0,29}$

Fiddle for this:
https://regexr.com/3cg7r